# asp.net core 2.0 not allowing environment variable to be overrided using command args

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Ive created a simple asp.net core 2.0 web api, and used the following line of code in my program.cs file

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BuildWebHost(args).Run();
}

public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
{
    var webHost = new WebHostBuilder()
     .UseKestrel()
     .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
     .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
     {
         var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
         config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
               .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
         config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
         config.AddCommandLine(args);
     }).UseStartup<Startup>()
       .Build();
    return webHost;
}
```

and when I run the application as a self-contained executable, I pass in a single command line argument

```
--environment dev
```

However, the value of the

```
env.EnvironmentName
```

property is NOT equal to dev. Instead its still the default of Production.

Has this been broken in asp.net core 2.0? This previously worked in asp.net core 1.1 by using the correct package

It appears that passing a command line arg --environment is no longer allowable

Answer (score 0):

After you published your app, in your publish folder (where you run `dotnet <application_name>.dll`) you can temporary change the environment with setting the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable.

Open a command prompt or powershell in your publish folder, then:

cmd => `set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development`

ps => `$Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Development"`

and then run `dotnet <application_name>.dll`.

These commands take effect only for the current window. When the window is closed, the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` setting reverts to the default setting or machine value. In order to set the value globally on Windows open the Control Panel > System > Advanced system settings and add or edit the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` value.

Comment: Right now I have dozens of asp.net core web apis running asp.net core 1.1 and they are all accepting command line argument in order to set the value for ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT. My goals is to use command line arguments since I need ability to run two different application on the same machine with different environments. Command line arguments has worked previously, so I need to know if its POSSIBLE to do so using command line argument approach. Also, using "dotnet" wont work, the apis are self contained and behind iis --> started by the asp.net core module for IIS, not dotnet myapp.dll.

Comment: This is important because there is a difference between self-contained vs. framework dependent. The example you show above is framework dependent, and therefore not a good example for this particular use case

Answer (score 0):

ConfigureAppConfiguration runs too late, environment must be configured on the host, not the app. You need to add the command line args to the host instead:

`var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddCommandLine(args).Build();
var webHost = new WebHostBuilder()
  .UseConfiguration(configuration)`

Here's a related bug where this has been improved in 2.1.0-preview1: https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/issues/221